# Where do I store a website's video files?

Tags: php, video, upload

I want to create a video upload site which allows users to upload videos.  Where do I need to store the video content, in db or in a webserver?

Comment: You usually don't want to store videos in a database.

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to store the video content on some sort of web server or storage service (like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)), then store the URLs (or some other type of pointer) to the videos in a database.

Comment: To add to Dorkus' answer: There might be a case for storing small documents, like letters and spreadsheets, in a database.  But video files are generally too large to do this well, unless they are confined to a very small size (say, about the same size as the largest email attachment, 10MB or smaller).